# python: remove element from list of dict based on key-value condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im trying to remove a element from a dict only if the condition is met.

For example,

```
dd = {'11': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 55}, {'xx': 260, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 35}], '22': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 40}, {'xx': 303, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 30}]}
```

Scenario:

```
channels = 60
```

there are two elements with key `xx = 259` in the nested dict above, I wish to keep only one element which is closer to the `channels = 60` value.

expected output:

```
dd = {'11': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 55}, {'xx': 260, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 35}], '22': [{'xx': 303, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 30}]}
```

I tried so far:

```
channels = 60
for key, values in dd.items():
    key = str(key)
    if key in dd:
        for elem in dd[key]:
            if elem['xx'] == 259:
                print(elem)
                # some logic here to check the closest value to channels and remove the furthest one
```

Which outputs:

```
{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 55}
{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 40}
```

UPDATED APPROACH:

```
    channels = 60
    xList = []
    for key, values in dd.items():
        key = str(key)
        if key in dd:
            for elem in dd[key]:
                if elem['xx'] == 259:
                    xList.append(elem['channels'])


    result =min(xList, key=lambda x: abs(x - 60))

    # find and remove elem from dict
    for key, values in dd.items():
        key = str(key)
        if key in dd:
            for elem in dd[key]:
                if elem['xx'] == 259:
                    if elem['channels'] == result:
                        pass
                    else:
                        print("delete this elem: ", elem)
                        dd[key].remove(elem)
    print(dd)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'11': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 55}, {'xx': 260, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 35}], '22': [{'xx': 303, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 30}]}
```

I managed to achieve the end goal, but I feel like this can certainly be improved. Any help?

Comment: Please update your question with your attempt at deleting an entry from a dict.

Comment: @quamrana updated it with what tried.

Comment: I was able to get the desired result but can this be improved with a better and perhaps faster approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for, without having to search for
matching items in the second loop (which remove() has to do), by keeping
the keys and indexes of all candidate elements, and then deleting all
but the one with the lowest delta value.

```
channels = 60
xList = []
for key, values in dd.items():
    for index,elem in enumerate(values):
        if elem['xx'] == 259:
            xList.append((abs(elem['channels']-channels),key,index)) # capture delta, key, and index

# this drops the lowest difference entry and sorts the remaining (deletions) in reverse index order
xList=sorted([(key,index) for (delta,key,index) in sorted(xList)[1:]],reverse=True)

# the deletions must be done from highest index to lowest index
for key,index in xList:  # pull indexes from highest to lowest
    del dd[key][index]

print(dd)
```

(Edit:  earlier version of code above had a misplaced parenthesis)

This version removes all but the closest *within each key* instead of overall:

```
channels = 60
for key, values in dd.items():
    xList = []
    for index,elem in enumerate(values):
        if elem['xx'] == 259:
            xList.append((abs(elem['channels']-channels),index)) # capture delta and index
    # this drops the lowest difference entry and sorts the remaining (deletions) in reverse index order
    xList=sorted([index for (delta,index) in sorted(xList)[1:]],reverse=True)
    for index in xList:  # pull indexes from highest to lowest
        del dd[key][index]
```

(I put processing within the loop and removed keys from the selection list)

Comment: Awesome, except just one thing. My solution only removes the dict elements that exceed that `channels` values, yours deletes all the elements except one.

Comment: I was under the impression you wanted to remove all entries but the closest.  I had another solution that kept the closest match for each key, but rejected it.

Comment: understood. Could you please add the other solution as well, that would keep the closest match for each key and remove any that is above. Thank you! :)

Comment: I edited the code which had a misplaced parenthesis.

Comment: @Lee Chun - I added alternate code to my answer to perform the function within each key instead of overall (notice the first set of code needed a small change too).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution a bit more compact than the one you have so far. The code itself is not an example of clarity, but it works reasonably fast. I have also extended your example dictionary, so we can test the case in which there are several sub-dictionaries with key 259.

```
from collections import defaultdict

CHANNELS = 60

dd = {'11': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 55},
             {'xx': 259, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 30},
             {'xx': 260, 'yy': 3, 'channels': 35}],
      '22': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 40},
             {'xx': 259, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 45},
             {'xx': 303, 'yy': 3, 'channels': 30}]}


# Nasty list comprehension to get the items where 'xx' == 259

ddlst = [[key, idx, valin['channels']] for key, val in dd.items()
         for idx, valin in enumerate(val) if valin['xx'] == 259]

ddlstkey = defaultdict(list)
for key, *vals in ddlst:
    ddlstkey[key].append(vals)
ddlstkey = dict(ddlstkey)

# Delete from the previous list the element that is closer to channels = 60

for k, i in ddlstkey.items():
    minval = min(ddlstkey[k], key=lambda x: abs(x[:][1] - CHANNELS))
    ddlstkey[k].remove(minval)

# Finally delete the non-minimum items from original dictionary

for key, vals in ddlstkey.items():
    for vl in reversed(vals):
        del dd[key][vl[0]]

print(dd)
```

This outputs:

```
{'11': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 1, 'channels': 55}, {'xx': 260, 'yy': 3, 'channels': 35}], '22': [{'xx': 259, 'yy': 2, 'channels': 45}, {'xx': 303, 'yy': 3, 'channels': 30}]}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I think if there is more than one element to be deleted in a given key, this will not work, because the index of the subsequent elements will change after the first deletion.  They must be deleted from high index to low index.  My solution is similar, but I like your use of `min` to eliminate the keeper from the delete list.  I think you just need to change your `for` statement to use `reversed(ddlst)`

Comment: @RufusVS thank you very much for the excellent feedback! I was missing this detail with the subsequent deletions, `reversed(ddlst)` was indeed necessary. I am very happy you liked my solution, I also like yours!